# Azure Management Certificate is forbidden (ForbiddenError)

Tags: powershell, azure, x509certificate

My goal is to use a powershell script to get an instance of an azure service with `Get-HostedService`.

As a preparation, I created a self-signed certificate and uploaded as a Management Certificate via the Azure Management portal, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg551722.aspx.

After that, I

- See my certificate and its thumbprint in `PS cert:\CurrentUser\My`
- The thumbprint matches the thumbprint I can see in manage.windowsazure.com > settings > management certificates

My test script just tries to create a `$service` instance and goes like this:

```
Add-PSSnapin WAPPSCmdlets
$cert = Get-Item cert:\CurrentUser\My\<thumbprint of certificate>
$service = Get-HostedService <my service name> -Certificate $cert -SubscriptionId <my subscription id>
```

The 3rd line (`Get-HostedService` command) results into:

```
Get-HostedService : HTTP Status Code: ForbiddenError - HTTP Error Message: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
```

The machine (A) I am trying to do this on is behind a corporate firewall. According to our IT there is no event in the firewall log that may indicate a problem. The same script works on a different machine (B) that is behind another firewall (in a DMZ). However, both machines have access to the internet.

I tried to use the same certificate (exported from machine A and imported into machine B ) as well as to create a new certificate for the new machine A.

On both machines, double-cllcking on the certificate (in the mmc snap-in) shows:

```
This CA Rot certificate is not trusted. To enable trust, install certificate in the trusted Root Certification Authorities store
```

and

```
You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate
```

I tried to add the certificate to "Trusted Root CAs" but that did not help.

The certificate is

- sha1 RSA 2048 bits
- not expired

What can I do to solve the problem or get more debugging information?

Comment: Does your Firewall also act as a Proxy server? I have seen this happening when I perform Service Management API operations (which is what PS Cmdlets are doing) with Fiddler running. Fiddler actually removes the certificate from the request.

Comment: Gaurav, thanks for your hint. I can't tell for sure at the moment, so far it is assumend that this is not the case (firewall does not remove the certificate). However, how could I check this? thanks.